# Linq to group by firstname lastname and select from a sub array

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using Entity Framework and perform a query on a database that returns a company which in turn has many contacts per company.

I have the two scenarios where i want to group the MyContacts which have the same first and last name.

Whilst i can loop through an array of new objects where the result is stored, I am using Entity Framework and it will be slow to have to load data more than once, so if possible I would prefer to maintain the objects as-is in a result set.

The plan is i can loop through the results array, make a change to the MyContacts object, and update the object into the EF repository.

The first scenario is grouping a contact list by name, but i am unsure on how to group without making a new class dataset.

The second scenario is more complex, i have a list of MyAccounts (each of which has a list of MyContacts), i would like to return the MyContacts for all the list, grouped by first and lastname, with the original classes returned if possible.

Many thanks, Chris.

**I have removed data access and made a simple example below:**

```
class MyAccount
{
    public string accountName { get; set; }
    public List<MyContact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

class MyContact
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname  { get; set; }
}

MyContact contactA = new MyContact() { firstname = "Chris", lastname = "b", ID = 100 };
MyContact contactB = new MyContact() { firstname = "Chris", lastname = "b", ID = 101 };
MyContact contactC = new MyContact() { firstname = "Peter", lastname = "Bread", ID = 102 };
MyContact contactD = new MyContact() { firstname = "James", lastname = "apple", ID = 103 };
MyContact contactE = new MyContact() { firstname = "Richard", lastname = "Brian", ID = 104 };
MyContact contactF = new MyContact() { firstname = "James", lastname = "apple", ID = 105 };

List<MyContact> contacts = new List<MyContact>();
contacts.AddRange(new MyContact[] { contactA, contactB, contactC, contactD, contactE, contactF } );
// how do i get a list of items, grouped by same first and lastname?

MyAccount companyA = new MyAccount() { accountName = "CompanyA", Contacts = new List<MyContact>() };
companyA.Contacts.AddRange(new MyContact[] { contactA, contactB, contactC });
MyAccount companyB = new MyAccount() { accountName = "CompanyB", Contacts = new List<MyContact>() };
companyB.Contacts.AddRange(new MyContact[] { contactA, contactB, contactC });
MyAccount companyC = new MyAccount() { accountName = "CompanyB", Contacts = new List<MyContact>() };
companyB.Contacts.AddRange(new MyContact[] { contactA, contactB, contactC, contactD, contactE });
List<MyAccount> companyList = new List<MyAccount>(new MyAccount[] { companyA, companyB, companyC });
// from the companyList, is there any way to get a list of MyContact types grouped by duplicate first and lastname?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
    var result = from c in contacts
                 group c by new { c.firstname, c.lastname } into g
                 select g.ToList();

    var result1 = from c in companyList.SelectMany(company => company.Contacts)
                  group c by new { c.firstname, c.lastname } into g
                  select g.ToList();
```

Now you get IEnumerable of Lists.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have changed my original code to include an ID, this ID would be important to access in the result set. How can this be done, and is there any way to have the results returned with a list of MyContact class types as opposed to anonymous type?

I have expanded on my intention/requirements in the original question regarding composing all parts of individual address books. Thanks.

Comment: Also the list of contacts, including duplicates should be present in the result set, in the example code above duplicates are removed. Regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're planning to have a lot of data, I'd seriously recommend you to use `HashSet` instead of a `List`. The main difference is that `HashSet` has O(1) speed for collision testing (searching for repeating properties), while if you use `List`, it uses O(n) algorithm. From what I understood, your final intention is to merge Lists of different adress books and get unique values. If you want to merge two Lists and get only the unique values, use linq's `Union` function, if you want to get only values that repeat in both lists, use `Instersect`